# Docker multi-stage build package unrecognized

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, uvicorn

I have a Dockerfile, where I want to run multistage builds, such that I can install python packages from Github (in `requirements.txt`) by using `slim` as `base` stage and then want to copy everything to an `alpine` image.

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11-slim AS base

# set working directory
WORKDIR /src

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


FROM python:3.11-alpine

COPY --from=base /src /src

WORKDIR /src

# add app
COPY . .
```

However, when I try to run things in docker-compose via

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

I get:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense as a multi-stage build, as you actually want the dependencies at runtime.

Comment: I could also use slim, but of course alpine would be cooler as it is smaller. The only thing that keeps me away from it is that is have a package in `requirements.txt` that looks like `git+https://${GITHUB_PAT}@github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git@<commit hash>`. If there is a way around it that would also be sufficient for me.

Comment: Then you should probably be working out how to install that in alpine; rather than installing it an OS you don't want then ignoring it in subsequent layers.

Comment: You copy src from base but pip in base does not install packages there so you essentially copy nothing

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the Dockerfile you show.  If you `RUN pip install ...`, it normally installs the Python packages into the "system" Python directory, probably under `/usr/local/lib/python3.11`, and not anywhere in the current directory.  The installed packages also wind up being very specific to the Python they were installed with, so you probably can't use a Debian-Python package set with an Alpine-Python image.

The trick I'd use here is to install packages into a Python virtual environment.  Both stages will need to have the same base image, but the second stage won't need things like a C compiler to build packages from source.

```bash
# Use a common base image
FROM python:3.11-slim AS base
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app

# First stage creates a virtual environment and installs packages.
FROM base AS build

# Install OS packages
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git # build-essential libfoo-dev libbar-dev

# Create and populate the virtual environment
RUN python -m venv /venv \
 && /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -r reuirements.txt

# Final stage is the image you'll actually run
FROM base
# RUN apt-get update \
#  && apt-get install -y libfoo1 libbar2
COPY --from=build /venv/ /venv/
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 8000
CMD uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

So note that both stages start from the same `base` image (an identical `python:3.11-slim` with a couple of common environment variables).  The first stage creates a virtual environment and `RUN pip install`.  The second `COPY`s the entire virtual environment, then also adds in the application code.

The comments in the two `apt-get install` lines are important.  If you're installing packages with C extensions that are not available as wheels, then you'll need a full C toolchain (`build-essential`) and various C library header files.  These are pretty large, but they only need to be present in the build image.  When you copy the virtual environment, you do not need the build tools but only the C runtime libraries.

(One advantage of using a Debian Python package base here is that it often can use Python wheel packages that don't require recompilation; Alpine generally can't, and so your images actually wind up being larger and much slower to build.)

In the Compose file, you should delete the `command:` override and the `volumes:` block that tries to inject the application source code.  Both of these things are already present in the image.